# Calculate Cumulative Mean and Standard Deviation of a list without FOR loops

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, map

I have a simple list `mylist={x_1,x_2,...,x_N};`.

Now I want to map a function over this list, e.g. the Mean and StandardDeviation functions, so that it will give me a list that looks like this:

```
f/@mylist = {f[{x_1}], f[{x_1, x_2}], f[{x_1, x_2, x_3}], ... , f[{x_1,x_2,...,x_N}]}
```

How can I achieve that? I know that I can use a simple loop to do so but I am wondering if Mathematica has a specific function for this kind of mapping.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Would using `Table` be an acceptable solution or would that count as a simple loop? While Mathematica has `Accumulate` which performs the operation you look for for `Plus`, I don't think there's a way to do a generalised accumulation with an arbitrary function like `Mean`. Neither is there a built-in to get all the prefixes of a list, so I guess using `Table` or `Array` might be the best you can get. (E.g. `Table[Mean@myList[[1 ;; i]], {i, Length@myList}]`)

Comment: mylist = {x1, x2, x3, xN}.  `f@Take[mylist, #] & /@ Range[4]` or `Mean@Take[mylist, #] & /@ Range[4]`, maybe

Comment: In the lines of @TomD, you could define a helper function for this: `ClearAll[MapAccumulate]; MapAccumulate[f_, list_List] := f@Take[list, #] & /@ Range@Length@list;` ... `MapAccumulate[f, mylist]`

Comment: @MartinBüttner I would say it is still acceptable, at least for me. :-)

Comment: @Kuba: I think it is safe to say that.

Comment: @kirma Yup It's very convenient. I'd say I'll stick to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

```
ClearAll[MapAccumulate];

MapAccumulate[f_, list_List] := f@Take[list, #] & /@ Range@Length@list;
```

Now you can do stuff like this:

```
MapAccumulate[Mean, mylist]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Aye carumbah - new versions**

```
lis = {x1, x2, x3, x4};
```

• Sol1:

```
FoldList[Append, {}, lis] // Rest
```

> {{x1}, {x1, x2}, {x1, x2, x3}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}}

• Sol2:

```
sol = FoldList[Join, lis]  /. Join->List
```

> {x1, {x1, x2}, {x1, x2, x3}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}}

One can then `Map` any desired function, e.g.

```
Map[Mean, sol]
```

Above work for numerical versions too.

**Earlier Suggestion**

My earlier suggestion (see comments from Kuba below) was:

```
Accumulate[lis] /. Plus -> List
```

... but that has some behavioural problems with numerical input.

Comment: Try this on `Range[5]`.

Comment: Trouble maker ! ;)

Comment: Ah, at least you've confessed :)

Comment: This is also problematic if `f[{x}] != x` for all single-element lists.

Comment: I found this only works for symbolic lists. :(

Comment: New version above ---------> all improved